# Is there any way to add "description" column in custom reports (for ticket)

Tags: freshdesk

I want to add description column in custom reports.

[image]

Comment: I don't think they let you add description in the report as it sometimes large of size than the other fields. Did you check with Freshdesk support?

Comment: Yes, I have gone through freshservice support site but i didn't find any clue there.

Comment: Perhaps, you could contact them by explaining your requirement. They know their product better than any